# UITextView background image

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview

How can I set up a background image to `UITextView`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can have an `UIImageView` containing the background image and the `UITextView` as siblings, then in Interface Builder move the text view to overlap the image view (or add them both to the same parent view if doing it programmatically). You also need to make sure that text view is not **opaque** and give it a **0% opacity background**.

Comment: In my mind this is the right answer, in oxigen's method, if the background image has a "bottom border" then the user will see it scroll along with the text view as they enter text.

Comment: So how exactly do you add a sibling to UIImageView?

Comment: @jacobronniegeorge just add UIImageView and UITextView to the View (that way they are siblings, e.g. children of the main View), and then use the left/right/top/bottom constraints to achieve the overlay.

Answer (score 45):

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame: window.frame];
textView.text = @"text\n text\n text";
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: textView.frame];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myImage.jpg"];
[textView addSubview: imgView];
[textView sendSubviewToBack: imgView];
[window addSubview: textView];
```

Comment: I think duncanwilcox's answer is preferable as the method described in this answer will cause the "background image" to scroll along with the content as the user types.

Comment: Remember to release alloced objects.

after:

    [textView addSubview: imgView];

add:

    [imgView release];

add to the end:

    [textView release];

Comment: And if desired for a better image quality,make the image resizable!

Answer (score 42):

**@durai:** Your image has a height limit after which white background will appear if empty background appears after it scrolls down then you can repeat the same image.

**This might be helpful:**

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Image.png"]];
```

Comment: upvoting - not sure why anyone would downvote this; it's a nifty solution.

Comment: Both this answer and the one by @duncanwilcox are good. It depends on if you want your background to scroll or not.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty good solution indeed, and considered elegant. +1, don't see the reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 11):

Just one clarification, when trying out answer #9 from **@oxigen**, I found out that this line:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: textView.frame];
```

Is relative to the `textView.frame`. So your `x` and `y` values need to be 0,0 if you want it to overlap completely which means you want something like:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:textView.bounds];
```

Comment: Or with less typing: ` (...) initWithFrame:textView.bounds`

Answer (score 6):

I found one simple method how to set background image.

h file

```
@interface FNTextView : UITextView

@end
```

m file

```
...
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.bgImage drawInRect:rect];

    [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (void)initHandler
{
    self.bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"textview_bg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 4, 4, 4)];
}
...
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[txtView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]]];
```

Answer (score 2):

For tiled background i like this solution

```
UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage];
textView.backgroundColor = color;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about, but you can try the following, assuming that your background image is handled by a UIImageView:

[myTextView addSubview: myImageView];

Note that you may need to change the value of the alpha/opaque properties of your UITextView.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 40)];
textView.text = @"this is a test \n this is test \n this is a test";
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: textView.frame];
img.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image.png"];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
[self.view insertSubview:img belowSubview:textView];
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers of @dulcanwilcox and @oxigen both work, but, an addition would be to make the background image resizable, in case the image is being used to show some kind of border.

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame: window.frame];
textView.text = @"Some text...";

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: textView.frame];
imgView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"image"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)];

[textView addSubview:imgView];
[textView sendSubviewToBack:imgView];

[window addSubview:textView];
```

Check out the documentation for [resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624102-resizableimagewithcapinsets).