# Drawing in a UITextView

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uitextview

I'm trying to make a `UITextView` look like a piece of paper with the red lines, margins, etc.

I haven't found anything that would allow me to use graphics in a `UITextView` and I can't use a `UITextField` because I need to allow multiple lines...

I've tried drawing in a normal `UIView` and then trying to blend that with the `UITextView` but that apparently wasn't the right approach.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need a background image? This thread may help:

[UITextView background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759658/uitextview-background-image)

Comment: Weird... I swear I tried that before and it didn't work... O well, not it works. Thank you so much