# Want to make a text editor.. how to apply background image to TextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITextView background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759658/uitextview-background-image)

I want to add a background image to a textview. Can it be done through the interface editor?
If not, what will be the code required to do so?

I want the text to scroll with the background image as the number of lines with text increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the following way, using patternImage. Multiple lines can be made, pattern will contain a single line :)

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"line.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put UIImageView with your desired image, and, above that, use textview with ClearColor Background.

Comment: but using it will not move my image with the text.. image remains constant and the text moves upwards.. :( help!!

Comment: ok then put both uiimageview and textview in to the scroll view  and disable the scrolling of the text view

Comment: >below one is  good  much easier …...

Comment: dont know why but after disabling the scrolling of text view, the scroll view is not scrolling @ runtime..

Comment: is there any other method to create a text editor of variable height with notepad like horizontal lines in the background between the text which move with the scrolling text??