# UIImageView as background of UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: description.frame];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"textview.png"];
[description addSubview: imgView];
[description sendSubviewToBack: imgView];
[imgView release];
```

where description here is a UITextView. I have an image that I would like to set as the background of this. However the resulting interface looks like this:

[image]

The size of the image is exactly the same as the size of the UITextView

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759658/uitextview-background-image

Comment: and I did the same exact thing as that post and yet the result I got is as above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,description.frame.size.width,description.frame.size.height)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"textview.png"];
[description addSubview: imgView];
[description sendSubviewToBack: imgView];
[imgView release];
```

the image is not placed at right place because your `description.frame.origin.x` != 0, its due to this reason you are getting bug.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of UITextView you can use the UILabel and set the UILable color to colorless. then you will get the desired output..

Answer (score 0):

You can add imageView(with you image) into your nib file and then place textView upon it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image as background as follows:

```
UITextView *view = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]];

[self.view addSubView: text];
```

Hope this helps