# How to add a UIView as background to a UITextView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uitextview

I'd like to add UIView with programmatically drawn lines as a background pattern to a UITextView field (The textview field should look a bit like a lined piece of paper with proper line height according to the typo in the UITextView).

Here's what the UIView draw code of the lines currently look like with some fixed values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 80.0, (215.0+i*21.0));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, (215.0+i*21.0));
}
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, false);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

I found that it is actually possible to assign a backgound image as UIColor to a UITextview (in this case "viewLogNote").

```
[[self viewLogNote]setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"UITextField_Background"]]];
```

Is there a way to do something similar with the custom drawing?

Comment: You might be able to salvage something from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759658/uitextview-background-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume your UIView is called view and UITextView is called textView. Try this and let me know if it works:

```
[textView addSubview: view];
[textView sendSubviewToBack: view];
```

Comment: `[textView insertSubviewAtIndex:0]` should have the same effect.

Comment: What if I want to append, keeping the text and add a new UIView? is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It might work for you to have the custom view underneath the text view and then set the background color of the text view to clear so you can see through the text view to the custom view behind it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But I would actually like the lines in the background scroll with the textview. That wouldn't work with this approach.