# show smiles in uitextview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

Any idea how to add smiles/images in UITextView? For displaying them I am using the Three20 library with the custom UILabel, but is there any way to add them in UITextView as well? I am interested in editing the field, adding text and images.

Comment: reffer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759658/uitextview-background-image

Answer (score 3):

```
\ue415  \ue056  \ue057  \ue414  \ue405  \ue106  \ue418
\ue417  \ue40d  \ue40a  \ue404  \ue105  \ue409  \ue40e
\ue402  \ue108  \ue403  \ue058  \ue407  \ue401  \ue40f
\ue40b  \ue406  \ue413  \ue411  \ue412  \ue410  \ue107
\ue059  \ue416  \ue408  \ue40c  \ue11a  \ue10c  \ue32c
\ue32a  \ue32d  \ue328  \ue32b  \ue022  \ue023  \ue327
\ue329  \ue32e  \ue32f  \ue335  \ue334  \ue021  \ue337
\ue020  \ue336  \ue13c  \ue330  \ue331  \ue326  \ue03e
\ue11d  \ue05a  \ue00e  \ue421  \ue420  \ue00d  \ue010
\ue011  \ue41e  \ue012  \ue422  \ue22e  \ue22f  \ue231
\ue230  \ue427  \ue41d  \ue00f  \ue41f  \ue14c  \ue201
\ue115  \ue428  \ue51f  \ue429  \ue424  \ue423  \ue253
\ue426  \ue111  \ue425  \ue31e  \ue31f  \ue31d  \ue001
\ue002  \ue005  \ue004  \ue51a  \ue519  \ue518  \ue515
\ue516  \ue517  \ue51b  \ue152  \ue04e  \ue51c  \ue51e
\ue11c  \ue536  \ue003  \ue41c  \ue41b  \ue419  \ue41a
\ue04a  \ue04b  \ue049  \ue048  \ue04c  \ue13d  \ue443
\ue43e  \ue04f  \ue052  \ue053  \ue524  \ue52c  \ue52a
\ue531  \ue050  \ue527  \ue051  \ue10b  \ue52b  \ue52f
\ue528  \ue01a  \ue134  \ue530  \ue529  \ue526  \ue52d
\ue521  \ue523  \ue52e  \ue055  \ue525  \ue10a  \ue109
\ue522  \ue019  \ue054  \ue520  \ue306  \ue030  \ue304
\ue110  \ue032  \ue305  \ue303  \ue118  \ue447  \ue119
\ue307  \ue308  \ue444  \ue441           
\ue436  \ue437  \ue438  \ue43a  \ue439  \ue43b  \ue117
\ue440  \ue442  \ue446  \ue445  \ue11b  \ue448  \ue033
\ue112  \ue325  \ue312  \ue310  \ue126  \ue127  \ue008
\ue03d  \ue00c  \ue12a  \ue00a  \ue00b  \ue009  \ue316
\ue129  \ue141  \ue142  \ue317  \ue128  \ue14b  \ue211
\ue114  \ue145  \ue144  \ue03f  \ue313  \ue116  \ue10f
\ue104  \ue103  \ue101  \ue102  \ue13f  \ue140  \ue11f
\ue12f  \ue031  \ue30e  \ue311  \ue113  \ue30f  \ue13b
\ue42b  \ue42a  \ue018  \ue016  \ue015  \ue014  \ue42c
\ue42d  \ue017  \ue013  \ue20e  \ue20c  \ue20f  \ue20d
\ue131  \ue12b  \ue130  \ue12d  \ue324  \ue301  \ue148
\ue502  \ue03c  \ue30a  \ue042  \ue040  \ue041  \ue12c
\ue007  \ue31a  \ue13e  \ue31b  \ue006  \ue302  \ue319
\ue321  \ue322  \ue314  \ue503  \ue10e  \ue318  \ue43c
\ue11e  \ue323  \ue31c  \ue034  \ue035  \ue045  \ue338
\ue047  \ue30c  \ue044  \ue30b  \ue043  \ue120  \ue33b
\ue33f  \ue341  \ue34c  \ue344  \ue342  \ue33d  \ue33e
\ue340  \ue34d  \ue339  \ue147  \ue343  \ue33c  \ue33a
\ue43f  \ue34b  \ue046  \ue345  \ue346  \ue348  \ue347
\ue34a  \ue349                   
\ue036  \ue157  \ue038  \ue153  \ue155  \ue14d  \ue156
\ue501  \ue158  \ue43d  \ue037  \ue504  \ue44a  \ue146
\ue50a  \ue505  \ue506  \ue122  \ue508  \ue509  \ue03b
\ue04d  \ue449  \ue44b  \ue51d  \ue44c  \ue124  \ue121
\ue433  \ue202  \ue135  \ue01c  \ue01d  \ue10d  \ue136
\ue42e  \ue01b  \ue15a  \ue159  \ue432  \ue430  \ue431
\ue42f  \ue01e  \ue039  \ue435  \ue01f  \ue125  \ue03a
\ue14e  \ue252  \ue137  \ue209  \ue154  \ue133  \ue150
\ue320  \ue123  \ue132  \ue143  \ue50b  \ue514  \ue513
\ue50c  \ue50d  \ue511  \ue50f  \ue512  \ue510  \ue50e
\ue21c  \ue21d  \ue21e  \ue21f  \ue220  \ue221  \ue222
\ue223  \ue224  \ue225  \ue210  \ue232  \ue233  \ue235
\ue234  \ue236  \ue237  \ue238  \ue239  \ue23b  \ue23a
\ue23d  \ue23c  \ue24d  \ue212  \ue24c  \ue213  \ue214
\ue507  \ue203  \ue20b  \ue22a  \ue22b  \ue226  \ue227
\ue22c  \ue22d  \ue215  \ue216  \ue217  \ue218  \ue228
\ue151  \ue138  \ue139  \ue13a  \ue208  \ue14f  \ue20a
\ue434  \ue309  \ue315  \ue30d  \ue207  \ue229  \ue206
\ue205  \ue204  \ue12e  \ue250  \ue251  \ue14a  \ue149
\ue23f  \ue240  \ue241  \ue242  \ue243  \ue244  \ue245
\ue246  \ue247  \ue248  \ue249  \ue24a  \ue24b  \ue23e
\ue532  \ue533  \ue534  \ue535  \ue21a  \ue219  \ue21b
\ue02f  \ue024  \ue025  \ue026  \ue027  \ue028  \ue029
\ue02a  \ue02b  \ue02c  \ue02d  \ue02e  \ue332  \ue333
\ue24e  \ue24f  \ue537
```

check this link for the respective images [Emoji Alerts](http://web.archive.org/web/20120830031251/http://www.easyapns.com/iphone-emoji-alerts)

U can use any of the above character set like... [TextViewVar setText:@"\ue333"];

Comment: What if I want to customize the emoji with my own icons? is this possible?

Comment: @Catalin   refer this link for more details  http://www.quora.com/iOS-Development/Is-it-possible-to-create-an-emoji-app-for-iOS-with-original-alternative-symbols

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 [aboutBni setText:@"\ue415"]
```